# babel: "No hyphenation patterns were loaded for the language 'Portuguese'"

Tags: errors, hyphenation, babel

I put in the preamble of my document:

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
```

When I compile as a PDF, I receive the output:

```
"No hyphenation patterns were loaded for(babel)
the language 'Portuguese'(babel)
I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead"
```

What am I doing wrong?

My main LaTeX editor is Kile.

Answer (score 6):

This problem usually belongs to MiKTeX users up to version 2.8. Upgrade to version 2.9 or enable the language in the MiKTeX setting program.

Also who has TeX Live/Ubuntu can have this problem and the solution is to install with Synaptic the package texlive-lang-portuguese.

Comment: While updating certainly is a good idea, I would think it is related to the language not being activated in the settings. Go to `Settings->Languages` and activate `portuguese`.

Comment: MikTeX 2.9 is only for Windows. I use Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dante It's important to specify system and TeX distribution in cases like yours. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You are not doing anything wrong. The only thing is that hyphenation for Portuguese appears not to be installed in your distribution. In [the babel CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/babel/) you can find all dictionaries.

You should download `portuges.ins` and `portuges.dtx`. Run `latex portuges.ins` to create the Portuguese dictionary.

Comment: OK, but... how do I run the file?

Comment: portuges.dtx is the source for the language definition file that babel loads.  _that_ is what complains about the lack of hyphenation tables; loading the tex portuguese language package loads the hyphenation tables (and rebuilds the formats as necessary); this has already been recommended

Answer (score 1):

On Fedora, I've managed to solve an almost identical error message by installing the `texlive-hyphen-portuguese` package. Hence, try running something like

```
sudo dnf install texlive-hyphen-portuguese
```

On Ubuntu, substitute `dnf` for `apt`; the package name may have a different name there too. On older Fedora versions, replace `yum` for `dnf`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite common problem.

You could not have the right packages installed in your system.
Try installing 
texlive-lang-portuguese

Should solve it!