# I'm not getting accentuation directly, even though I'm loading the package inputenc package with the latin1 option

Tags: accents

I'm not getting accentuation directly, even though I'm loading the package `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`

My packages are:

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel} % pacote portugues brasileiro
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc} % pacote para acentuacao direta
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb} % pacote matematico
\usepackage{graphicx} % pacote grafico
\usepackage{times} % fonte times
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{amsxtra}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}  % diagramas xy em LaTeX
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

is something wrong?

Comment: Hello, welcome to TeX.sx! We need to use a proper font encoding, so add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble as well. Hopefully this will fix things. `:)`

Comment: Instead of `inputenc`, try with `\usepackage{selinput}` immediately followed by `\SelectInputMappings{adieresis={ä},germandbls={ß}}` (copy-paste from here). When you compile you should find in the log file a line telling you `Package selinput Info: Encoding '...' selected`. This should tell you with more precision what encoding your editor is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, works quite good when using with Spanish:

```
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

Comment: Now why would you want to select the `portuguese` option if you want to typeset Spanish text? Choose `spanish` instead.

Comment: I was just trying to say that this form has worked fine for me when writing in spanish, so if you just change it for `portuguese` instead of `spanish` you shouldn't have problems with Portuguese accentuation, I've already tried it.

Comment: You'll probably get your hyphenation wrong, however.

Comment: Then that would be a distribution problem. For fixing it he could [try this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19634/babel-no-hyphenation-patterns-were-loaded-for-the-language-portuguese).